# React development without webpack, is there a way using just Gulp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gulp

While there are things I like about Webpack, but I only like it for so long, as soon as it gets bigger than 15 lines, it gets so cryptic, so unconfigurable, and so time consuming, that I rather not use it for anything but two things.

1. To transform es6/jsx into current javascript format.
2. To solve dependency graph.

I rather do hotreloading, sass -> css, cleaning etc either directly in npm scripts or Gulp (preferred).

However, I am just getting started with React, and only thing I can see Webpack doing in React Universe is transforming JSX+ES6 into ES5 format. Is there more that I've not encountered yet for which Webpack is required in React.

I want to simply not use Webpack at all if possible. If it's all that it does for React then I want to know this: Using Gulp how can I do two things mentioned above?

Comment: did you... search react gulp? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-react is there a reason the first result won't work? (i wouldn't know, never used it)

Answer (score 1):

A few considerations before you made this decision. Like you said, you are **learning** react, so probably you don't know the best tools to use in React Environment, but you should **try** more before use gulp.

Take a look at this snippet, and I'll explain to you detailed.

```
 devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 8080,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  entry: './src/app/App.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: 'chunk.[hash].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: [ ['es2015',{ modules: false }], 'react'],// insert ] 
          plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader',
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /.(mp4|png|jpg|woff(2)??|eot|otf|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=\.]+)?$/,
        use: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [CleanPlugin, HTMLWebpackPluginConfig, ExtractTextPluginCSS, FaviconPlugin],
  devtool: 'cheap-source-map',
};
```

**devServer** : It's the object that configures the [webpack-dev-server](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) an amazing tool to use in development mode, and see the output with hot-reloading.

**rules** : This is the most important part of the webpack configuration file, the rules test the extension of your file and give them a special treatment, according the rules created.

In the `.JSX` test they will test all of your .jsx files, the calls inside your root folder. The presets are used to create special rules for the .jsx and the plugins I used only one that enables [spread-opertor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

The rules for `.css` files I had to use 2 loaders, one for css and another if they first one fail (Fallback).

Now your point, the scss files, I use scss with css modules, they create chunk files for every css output with some weird name. With this loader you can use simply importing then.[CSS-MODULES](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-css-modules-methodology/) is being used for each .scss files that I created for every component, looks complicated? Check the url. e.g. ComponentA.JS, ComponentB.JS, ComponentA.scss, ComponentB.scss

The last rule, is for static files images and fonts, not much to explain here.

The plugins lines, it's a must, you have to insert all the plugins that you used in your configuration file. The Last but not least the `devtool` line with source-maps you can inspect your minified code inside chrome (or other) devTools, I like to use this tool with the debugger.

I hope it helps a litle to get you in the direction, but even if you already tried this and want to use gulp with react: https://jonsuh.com/blog/integrating-react-with-gulp/